# send POST request to custom URI in default browser

Tags: c#, .net, post, httpwebrequest

I need to open system default browser and send to some custom URI POST data. So I have two part of code: first - opens def browser and another must send POST data to it, but does not do it.

What can you say about it?

```
enter code here private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string browser = string.Empty;
        RegistryKey key = null;
        try
        {
            key = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(@"HTTP\shell\open\command", false);

            //trim off quotes
            browser = key.GetValue(null).ToString().ToLower().Replace("\", "");
            if (!browser.EndsWith("exe"))
            {
                //get rid of everything after the ".exe"
                browser = browser.Substring(0, browser.LastIndexOf(".exe")+4);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (key != null) key.Close();
        }
        //open default system browser
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(browser, strURL.Text);
```

//***************************************************

```
        // Convert string data into byte array 
        string strData = "Name=Sergiy&Age=21";
        byte[] dataByte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strData);

        HttpWebRequest POSTRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(strURL.Text);
        POSTRequest.Method = "POST";
        // Set the content type - Mine was xml.
        POSTRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        POSTRequest.KeepAlive = false;
        POSTRequest.Timeout = 5000;
        POSTRequest.ContentLength = dataByte.Length;
        // Get the request stream
        Stream POSTstream = POSTRequest.GetRequestStream();
        // Write the data bytes in the request stream
        POSTstream.Write(dataByte, 0, dataByte.Length);

        //Get response from server
        HttpWebResponse POSTResponse = (HttpWebResponse)POSTRequest.GetResponse();

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the only control you have of the browser is what URL it opens. You might be able to pass it a file://some/path URL which has the code you want to run as javascript in it. The browser would start, go to the file:// you specified, run the javascript in the file and then the results of the post will show in the browser.